# Woocommerce set all products to featured products from mysql query

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have a woocommerce store and I try to select from Mysql all products and set them as "Featured" products or set them as Non "Featured" products.

I have found the following query that set post_status to whatever I want. I quess that I just have to replace post_status to something else that set products as "featured" products or as no "featured" product.

```sql
UPDATE wp_posts 
SET post_status = 'Published' 
AND post_type = 'product'
OR post_type = 'product_variation'
```

Comment: WooCommerce is a commercial product with a skilled support team. Talk to them before hacking MySql to do wholesale changes like this. At least make a backup of your database before you try this stuff. Woo products' database representations are surpirisingly intricate.

Comment: What do you expect that this query would do?  For whatever it's worth... "Featured" is a taxonomy, so it wouldn't be in wp_posts.

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason you want to hack this into the MySQL database directly? The proper approach would be to use the WC API in order to do so.

An example that uses an array of WC products:

```
foreach ( $products as $product ) {
    $productObj = $product->get_product();
    $productObj->set_featured(true);
    $productObj->save();
}
```

Comment: I think it's faster from MySQL database and would like to do it manually.  I have an issue with some products that for some reason are not showing in my site or in category while they are published. So I have found that if i make those products featured or non featured then somehow it triggers the products and then make them show up again on site. So I would like to test it and make all products featured through database and see if that works. If I had to do it manually from wordpress , it will take for ever for 30k products and it will stress server,.

Comment: For 30k product you will indeed need some sort of corn or an ajax call. Hacking this directly into the MySQL database is not likely to help, as the event that "fixes" the products for you is likely somewhere in the chain of PHP functions run by WP or WC every time you make a product featured.
I'd rather spend some more time investigating and finding the actual problem if I were you. As always, it might be a flag for a bigger/another issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following custom PHP code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false ); // Don't load theme support functionality
require( './wp-load.php' );
     //echo $end_datenew;
     global $wpdb;
     global $woocommerce;


// The SQL query
$results = $wpdb->get_results( "
    SELECT  p.ID as product_id
    FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p
    
    WHERE p.post_type LIKE 'product'
    AND p.post_status LIKE 'publish'
    AND p.post_parent = '0'
" );


foreach($results as $result)
{
    $wpdb->insert('h3wp_term_relationships', array(
    'object_id' => $result->product_id,
    'term_taxonomy_id' => '20',
    'term_order' => '0', // ... and so on
));

}
```